# Access dependencies available in Scala but no PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to access the dependencies of an RDD. In Scala it is a pretty simple code:

```
scala> val myRdd = sc.parallelize(0 to 9).groupBy(_ % 2)
myRdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Iterable[Int])] = ShuffledRDD[2] at groupBy at <console>:24

scala> myRdd.dependencies
res0: Seq[org.apache.spark.Dependency[_]] = List(org.apache.spark.ShuffleDependency@6c427386)
```

But dependencies is not available in PySpark. Any pointers on how I can access them?

```
>>> myRdd.dependencies
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute 'dependencies'
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no supported way to do it, because it is not that meaningful. You can

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3]).map(lambda x: x)
deps = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD.toRDD(rdd._jrdd).dependencies()
print(deps)
## List(org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency@63b86b0d)

for i in range(deps.size()):
    print(deps.apply(i))

## org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency@63b86b0d
```

but I don't think it will get you far.

Comment: This is perfect, it is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!